# Sumar columnas con linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Necesito sumar varias columnas y devolverlas en una lista.
Pero en dos columnas voy a sumar poniendole una condición.

SQL

```
SELECT 
SUM(MontoInicial)AS MontoInicial, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimiento = 1 THEN Ingreso END) AS Ingreso,
SUM(CASE WHEN TipoMovimiento = 2 THEN Ingreso END) AS Devolucion,
SUM(Egreso)AS Egreso    
FROM MovimientoCajas
WHERE CAST(Fecha as date) = CAST('20181219' as date) AND PuntoEmisionId = 4
GO
```

Intento replicarlo en LINQ

```
var result = from m in context.MovimientoCajas
                where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Fecha) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
                      && m.PuntoEmisionId == puntoEmision
                select new MontoCajaExtend()
                {
                    MontoInical = Convert.ToDouble(m.MontoInicial),
                    Ingreso = m.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Ingreso
                        ? Convert.ToDouble(m.Ingreso)
                        : Convert.ToDouble(0),
                    Devolucion = m.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Devolucion
                        ? Convert.ToDouble(m.Ingreso)
                        : Convert.ToDouble(0),
                    Egreso = Convert.ToDouble(m.Egreso)
                };
```

Me falta aplicar SUM voy a devolver una lista.

Aplicando la recomendación de Leandro

```
var result = from m in context.MovimientoCajas
                where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Fecha) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
                      && m.PuntoEmisionId == puntoEmision
                group m by 1
                into g
                select new MontoCajaExtend()
                {
                    MontoInical = g.Sum(x => x.MontoInicial),
                    Ingreso = g.Sum(x => x.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Ingreso ? x.Ingreso : 0),
                    Devolucion = g.Sum(x => x.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Devolucion ? x.Ingreso : 0),
                    Egreso = g.Sum(x => x.Egreso)
                };
```

Me da el resultado esperado.

Seguimiento en el Profile

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
[GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C3], 
[GroupBy1].[A3] AS [C4], 
[GroupBy1].[A4] AS [C5]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
    SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1], 
    SUM([Filter1].[A2]) AS [A2], 
    SUM([Filter1].[A3]) AS [A3], 
    SUM([Filter1].[A4]) AS [A4]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        1 AS [K1], 
        [Extent1].[MontoInicial] AS [A1], 
        CASE WHEN (1 = [Extent1].[TipoMovimiento]) THEN [Extent1].[Ingreso] ELSE cast(0 as decimal(18)) END AS [A2], 
        CASE WHEN (2 = [Extent1].[TipoMovimiento]) THEN [Extent1].[Ingreso] ELSE cast(0 as decimal(18)) END AS [A3], 
        [Extent1].[Egreso] AS [A4]
        FROM [dbo].[MovimientoCajas] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Fecha], 102) ,  102)) = (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102))) OR ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Fecha], 102) ,  102) IS NULL) AND (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102) IS NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[PuntoEmisionId] = @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Filter1]
    GROUP BY [K1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0='2018-12-20 12:54:56.4477337',@p__linq__1=4
```

Efectivamente como dice Leandro no agrupa y no esperaba agrupar mas bien me parece es un truco para conseguir Sum en g.

[image: monto lista]

Necesito hacer esas condiciones para que me pueda filtrar los datos exactos.
¿como debería ser mi query?

Comment: no entendi, que es ese "group m by 1", eso no significa nada

Comment: @LeandroTuttini voy a modificar el código de la pregunta lo que intento es aplicar un select case y sumar las columnas.

Comment: pero alli no estas devolviendo una lista, es mas el SELECT seguro devuelve siempr eun solo registro, porque sumas todos los campos no defines ningun GROUP BY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes aplicar el filtro sore los datos y luego solo sumar las propiedades de forma individual

```
var result = (from m in context.MovimientoCajas
              where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Fecha) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
                      && m.PuntoEmisionId == puntoEmision
              select m).ToList();

var MontoInical = result.Sum(x=> x.MontoInical);
var Ingreso = result.Where(m=>m.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Ingreso)
                    .Sum(x=> x.Ingreso);
var Devolucion = result.Where(m=> m.TipoMovimiento == MovimientoCajaType.Devolucion)
                       .Sum(x=>x.Devolucion);
var Egreso = result.Sum(x=>x.Egreso);
```

Igual algo me suena raro al no aplicar filtro por tipo de movimiento para el moto inicial y egreso, pero quiero pensar que estos campos permiten null por lo que se completan segun corresponda

Comment: En monto inicial es un solo campo, egreso igual no aceptan valores null(monto inicial, ingreso, egreso, saldo). Ingreso lo uso para ingreso y devoluciones de dinero es por eso que valido el tipo de movimiento.

Comment: Agregue una query en linq que me funciona en mi post inicial, me gustaría que la revises.

Comment: usar "group m by 1" no aplica, no estas agrupando por nada

Comment: Efectivamente no agrupo nada pero te comento que mi intención no era agruparlo mas bien es un truco que lo usan para obtener el sum en g. Igualmente hice el seguimiento de la consulta en el Profile y no agrupa, pongo la consulta en mi publicación inicial.

Comment: Gracias por la solución Leandro, excelente.